# Google Drive Storage Purchase Link for target account

Tags: google-drive-api

The normal purchase link for Google Drive is https://www.google.com/settings/storage/
I'd like to ensure this link to be open for a specific account, something like:

https://www.google.com/settings/storage/?authuser=target@account.com

This solution works only for already signed-in accounts.

Comment: Interesting feature request. Do you mean for users who are logged into more than one account?

Comment: I want to ensure that the user will buy space for the target account and not for the current active session. In the case user is already logged in with this account but it's not the active one, what I expect is to switch the account. In the case user is not logged in with the target account, what I expect is to show a login page. In the final case that the user is logged in with the same target account there is nothing to do.

Comment: OK, that is an interesting use-case. I'll see if it is something we might take on. I doubt it will be soon, though.

Comment: Google Drive Application can do what I'm trying to accomplish. If you try to buy more space trough the Mac OSX Native application, the webpage opens with the correct user (even if the user was not logged in)